# Isolating users running containers in the same account

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, container, sandbox

Multiple users are running container images on the **same** user account on a supercomputer ("**service account**"). Each container mounts a folder that contains sensitive data. One service account user shall not be able to access the data from another service account user. I know that "use different user accounts for each user" would be a solution, but this solution is not applicable here, everyone needs to use the same service account.

Bwrap with temporary tmpfs mount file systems would be a solution, but unfortunately the installed container runtimes (Singularity and Sarus) prevent me from using bwrap. For example, Sarus checks whether a certain set of files is owned by root, but bwrap creates a new user namespace such that these files are then owned by nobody (not sure whether an unprivileged installation of Singularity would be a way out).

My idea would be to sort of "redirect" the file system operations performed by a container to a bwrap'ed process that stores the sensitive files in a tmpfs. For example, if the container wants to write a file into said folder, the file is instantly forwarded to a bwrap'ed process that forwards it into a tmpfs. Or when the container tries to read a file from that directory, the bwrap'ed process forwards the file from the tmpfs and hands it directly over to the container. There could/should be some form of access control, like for example prepending a secret to each file system operation and only handing out a file if the correct secret was used.

My first idea was to program some kind of server that listens at a socket mounted at that directory, not sure if this would work.

Next, I discovered that it is easy to **redirect** outputs of a command to another process e.g.

ls > /proc/5555/fd/1

and I have the feeling this could lead to a very easy solution.

A solution could look like this:

- the container reads and writes from/to a folder that is mounted into a bwrap'ed process
- every file that is "written" to the folder is prepended by a password and directly taken over by the bwrapped process (e.g. a shell script) which redirects it to a tmpfs and therefore hides it from other users
- conversely, when the container wants to read a file from this fake directory it also prepends a password and the bwrap'ed process directly forwards the file from the tmpfs to the container.

I have the feeling this could be doable with a few simple commands (like redirects), but I'm unable to wrap my head around it.

I don't see how a folder (or mount point in general) can act as an automatic redirector to a process in the manner described above.

Maybe my solution idea is also entirely misleading and there are better ways to address this, I'm happy about every clue. I also thought about nesting containers and having a writable layer on the outer container, but this again is not easy to achieve with HPC container runtimes like Singularity.

Every solution must work in userland without sudo rights.

Edit: Here something I tried:

```
> bwrap --dev-bind / / --tmpfs ~/testfolder/sandbox/ bash
> sarus run debian cat /etc/os-release
[73526.403627484] [daint101-28645] [main] [ERROR] Error trace (most nested error last):
#0   checkThatPathIsRootOwned at "SecurityChecks.cpp":78 Path "/apps/daint/system/opt/sarus/1.3.2/etc/sarus.json" must be owned by root in order to prevent other users from tampering its contents. Found uid=65534, gid=65534.
```

or with Singularity

```
> bwrap --dev-bind / / --tmpfs ~/testfolder/sandbox/ bash
> singularity exec ubuntu_latest.sif cat /etc/os-release
INFO:    Convert SIF file to sandbox...
FATAL:   while extracting ubuntu_latest.sif: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : No setuid installation found, for unprivileged installation use: ./mconfig --without-suid
: exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you please provide some specific context: the system you are using, commands that you have tried, the output of commands, that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I have added commands that I have tried and their outputs.

Comment: It's probably better if you break down your problem into simple steps and then ask specific questions about problems with these. Otherwise your problem is [too broad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to be handled as a question here

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to narrow it down. The problem is simple: how can I sandbox a folder in a Linux user account such that it is invisible and inaccessible by other sessions of the same user. Bwrap would be a solution, but it seems bwrap can't be used with HCP container runtimes like Singularity.